# What are the tricks about importing modules?

Tags: python, django, module

I am working on a django project. In `views.py` I invoked a function from `custom.py` . The problem is it is working nicely. But I didn't write something like:

```
from .custom import *
```

or

```
import custom
```

In a sentence, there is not the the word '`custom`' anywhere in `views.py`.

1. Why it's working? Is there any other way to import module that i don't know about? What is it?
2. Or any kind of django trick?

addition:

1. The custom.py also did not import views.py
2. custom.py has imported models.py

Comment: Can you show us the contents of both the files?

Comment: Also, do you mean _statement_ instead of _sentence_?

Comment: I'm sorry, but are some security issues about the project. I neither could put any kind of demon as it is useless in this case. So I explained in details.

Comment: Then can you show us a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead?

Comment: Do you really think its a matter of concern! statement or sentence ? to avoid such things, I also requested to stick to the topic in footer.

Comment: What is the name of the function from `custom.py` that you are calling? Maybe there is a built-in function with that name by accident?

Comment: Calm down bro I just asked

Comment: The question about statement or sentence was in view of those words having fixed meaning in programming. I think you did not mean either but just the actual sentence in your post, so this seems like a misunderstanding. Nonetheless, please keep a polite attitude, in particular as you are asking for help.

Comment: @DavidWierichs The name is `balance(**kwargs)` . If i rename it from `custom.py` it shows error in `views.py`. So I believe, It is calling that function.

Comment: Alright. There seems to be something wrong in the details, then. A MWE would be very helpful to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your `views.py` file is importing from another module which imports the function you are using.

models.py

```py
from .custom import my_function
```

views.py

```py
from .models import *

# my_function will be available
```

This occurs because the `import *` statement imports all functions and classes, including anything that has already been imported into that module. There is some information about it [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

You can avoid this by only importing the specific functions and classes you need, eg:

views.py

```py
from .models import PersonModel, ProductModel
```

Comment: I didn't know about such behavior/mechanism of python. Can you please help me understand this thing better? How does it work actually? And Of course thanks a lot. I've this kind of pattern in my project.

Comment: In last line of `models.py` there is `from .custom import *` . And `views.py` imported `models.py`

Comment: I've added a bit more detail and a link to the python docs. They don't really make it clear that this is a consequence of using `import *` but it can cause problems.